# Where has the Sign Out button gone?

Tags: ingress

The sign out button seems to have disappeared from the device tab in Ingress.

How are you now supposed to sign out??

Comment: I still have it in 1.67.1, what version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still the first button under the "Device" menu which is the last tab on the menu bar which opens when you press the "OPS" button on the radar screen.

Why do you want to "sign out" of the game? To save your data plan or is it something else?

Comment: Thanks, it seems that on that device I only had one google account set up which apparently disables the sign out button.

Comment: I have an account on both sides. I got bored when I got to level 10 so I started an account for the opposition.

Comment: @Roaders Playing as multiple agents is against the terms of service. Please stop. You can, however, switch affiliation. See https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2892252?hl=en However, there are many ways to play Ingress. Have you considered asking a question about how to have fun in your original L10 situation?

Comment: I didn't realise this was not allowed. Thanks for the reply.